# jquery mobile 1.4.2 scroll to div after pageContainer change

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, scroll, onchange

after not finding a way to use anchor position after pageContainer change event in a multipage ajax enabled mobile application, I have tried to investigate if it is possible to silent scroll to a specific div element after that event, but without success.

Code is:

```
$("#myPage").html('<div id="mydiv">Hello</div>');
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#myPage");
$('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#mydiv').offset().top}, 'slow');
```

$('#mydiv').offset().top is always 0!

Even if I define this event:

```
$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function(e, ui) {
    var pageId = $('body').pagecontainer('getActivePage').prop('id');

    if (pageId == 'myPage')
    {
       $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#mydiv').offset().top}, 'slow');
    }
});
```

scroll is not triggered.

Basically my need is to change html of a page, change page to this one and scroll to a specific div which is dynamically created.

Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this same problem. I cannot believe how complicated it is to do this. The problem is that in the context you call `animate()` your div `#mydiv` is not displayed and therefore has an `offset()` of 0. This should be fixed by your `on()`, but you have to make sure to declare it *before* you change the page. I believe that (as of jQM 1.4) only `body` can be the `.selector` mentioned in the [documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-show).

The following works for me:

```
$("body").on("pagecontainershow", function(event, ui) {
    if($.mobile.activePage.attr('id') == "myNewPage" && ui.prevPage[0].id == "myOldPage")
        $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: $("#mydiv").offset().top}, 0);
});
$("body").pagecontainer("change", "#myNewPage");
```

You might look into [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) if the show event should only be handled once.

EDIT: Made [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PKuQjcS9PIMa64f58HPC?p=preview) based on above code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", function(){
    $("#click_me").click(function (e) {
      $("body").on("pagecontainershow", function(event, ui) {
        if($.mobile.activePage.attr('id') == "two" && ui.prevPage[0].id == "one")
          $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: $("#after_hello").offset().top}, 500);
      });
      $('body').pagecontainer('change', '#two');
    });
  });
</script>
```

And the summarized HTML:

```
<div id="one" data-role="page">
  <div data-role="main">
    <button id="click_me">Click to change and scroll</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="two" data-role="page">
  <div data-role="main">
    <div>...</div>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <div id="after_hello">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT 2: OP provided a plunker that needed just one change to work. Here is the [modified version](http://plnkr.co/edit/x4QPVY8tCGDMSPf3w7S8?p=preview). I changed the animate selector from `$("html,body")` to `$("#maintesto")`. This is probably needed due to the fixed header. I also added more "lorem ipsum" content to see the effect on my larger screen.

Comment: Thanks, but even if now $("#mydiv").offset().top is ok, scroll is not performed. 
I have noticed a strange behaviour: scroll is performed if I resize browser before calling animate.

Comment: Strange indeed. Do you get the same behavior if you use the native `window.scrollTo(0, $("#mydiv").offset().top)`?

Comment: Yes. I also have to use: $(document).on('pagecontainershow' because $('body').on('pagecontainershow' is not triggered neither by $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change"...nor by $("body").pagecontainer("change"

Comment: This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PKuQjcS9PIMa64f58HPC?p=preview) works for me in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari (latests versions). Let me know if you have any questions about it.

Comment: I made a plunker which illustrates my issues (no scrolling) here: http://plnkr.co/edit/TFHXDe2vUrFoNPHsswp1?p=info

Comment: Hey, good news. If you change your animate selector to `$("#maintesto")` instead of `$("html,body")` then it will work. I'm not sure why you need to do that in your case. I had the idea because you were using a fixed header, which meant that the whole window wasn't scrolling, just the `data-role="main"` part.